# How to make a CSS grid set its height based on the size of elements without squeezing?

Tags: css

I have a CSS grid with a dynamic number of elements. I set it up with this code:

```
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
```

This fits in nicely.. creates a grid with a number of squares that fits in 3 columns. Now the problem happens when the number of elements are bigger than what fits in the screen height. Instead of automatically adjusting the height to fit in those elements at 200px (the template size), newly added cells are shrunk down at the bottom.

If I simply remove height:100%, then all elements get shrunk and don't respect the 200px / 200px rule. How to make it work?

Comment: `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);` ---> `grid-auto-rows:  200px;`

Comment: Best solution ever. Thank you.